# re-raise exception from method as argument

Tags: python, exception

I have a method that needs some wrapping called joule, so I wrap that `joule` method inside a wrapper called `respond` (which you will see shortly):

```
someclass.respond(somemodule.joule(someArgument, someStrategy), 202)
```

I have a wrapper called `respond`:

```
@classmethod
def respond(cls, method, successStatus):
    try:
        method, successStatus

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'status': 500,
            'message': str(e)
        }
```

The actual method that gets called and raises an `Exception`:

```
def joule(params, strategy):
    try:
        return strategy(params)

    finally:
        session.rollback()
        conn.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
```

For some reason, the re-raised exception does not seem to get caught in the respond wrapper! Can you folks help me understand what am I doing incorrectly here?

If this helps, the exception being thrown by sqlalchemy is (please note that this is a scenario being forcibly created to handle the exception correctly):

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, u"Table 'matrix.vmop_queue' doesn't exist") 'LOCK TABLES vmop_queue WRITE' ()
```

Comment: huh? I don't have any idea what is being called here. You don't seem to wrap your `joule` method in `respond`, and even if you did, `respond` doesn't call either `method` or `successStatus` so...

Comment: Invoking `return` from inside `except` is probably not what you intend to do. It's also weird to have an `except` block at all inside of `joule` as it appears to do nothing.

Comment: @AdamSmith joule is the actual "method" being called from respond.

Comment: @b4hand how do I re raise the exception? I want to make sure I clear some locks before I handle the exception.

Comment: @waka-waka-waka I disagree. In your code, `joule` is not being called anywhere. If your sample code does not reflect the problem you're having, then please edit your sample code!

Comment: You can use `try...finally` without `except`. The default behavior is for the exception to pass through if you don't have an `except` block.

Comment: @AdamSmith done editing!

Comment: Can you include the exception that is being thrown? Also, the invocation of `joule` appears to take two parameters, but you are passing only one in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how exception handling works. Exception handling operates on the stack frame of called functions.

In the example you give, `someclass.respond` does not actually invoke `somemodule.joule`, instead wherever the line that you have written in your example, which is some outer context is the place that receives the uncaught exception. Thus `someclass.respond` can't possibly handle the exception thrown by `somemodule.joule`.

There are other ways to achieve what you are trying to accomplish, but I would need more context in order to give you a better suggestion.

To make this a bit more concrete, let's say that `foo` contains the example line you gave:

```
def foo():
    someclass.respond(somemodule.joule(someArgument, someStrategy), 202)
```

You could add the `try` block to `foo` to handle the exception thrown by `somemodule.joule`. This would look like this:

```
def foo():
    try:
        someclass.respond(somemodule.joule(someArgument, someStrategy), 202)
    except Exception as e:
        pass # do something with the exception here
```

Alternatively, if the whole purpose for `someclass.respond` is to handle this exception, then you should move the invocation of `somemodule.joule` *inside* of `someclass.respond`. You could even do this more than one way. You could generically take a function and its arguments, and apply that function to the arguments inside of `someclass.respond` or you could just directly do the invocation inside of `someclass.respond`.

Let's take the first approach, since you've said that you don't want to repeat the exception handling. I'll call this new method `exception_catcher`:

```
def exception_catcher(func, *args):
    try:
        return func(*args)
    except Exception as e:
        pass # do whatever you want to the exception
```

Now the `foo` context will look like this:

```
def foo():
    exception_catcher(somemodule.joule, someArgument, someStrategy)
```

Note that `exception_catcher` is taking `somemodule.joule` as an argument, and the remaining arguments will be passed to `somemodule.joule` from within `exception_catcher`.

Comment: Thanks much for clarifying this. I have a REST API written in flask. The module that has the REST URL's simply calls the work to be done called joule, which inturn calls a strategy on how to execute it. The joule task may produce exceptions which are being handled in the "respond" handler. This was my initial idea.

Comment: ^ Problem with having try, except's for foo is that each foo() is a REST endpoint and my code will be filled with try: except: blocks. So thought it will be better if I clean this out a bit.

Comment: @waka-waka-waka: It is possible to extract the exception handling. I'm in the process of updating my answer to include potential extractions.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up rewriting it the same way and saw your answer :) But how is calling func(*args) - new way different from func --> the old way I initially posted.

Comment: The difference is the parenthesis in the `foo` context. In Python, functions are first class objects, and can be invoked or passed as a value. I'm passing `somemodule.joule` as a value, but you were invoking it directly. Passing it by value allows it to be invoked in the inner stack frame, which is required for the exception handling to work.